# Virtual Box is not working

Tags: windows, macos, virtualbox, macos-sierra

I want to run macOS Sierra within a virtual box. I was following this manual on youtube: 
[Manual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BFEAtlT5xc&feature=youtu.be)

When I want to start the virtual machine there is this error:

> Configuration error: Invalid config value(s) for the EFI device (VERR_PDM_DEVINS_UNKNOWN_CFG_VALUES).
>
> Fehlercode:
>   E_FAIL (0x80004005)
>   Komponente:
>   ConsoleWrap
>   Interface:
>   IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

How can I solve this problem?

What I already tried out is to change the chipset from "ICH9" to "PIIX3" and disable "Activate EFI"

Settings: 4GB RAM, 128MB for Graphic, 2CPU, disable floppy disk. Working with MacOS Sierra as an ISO File. I am working with Windows 10 (64-Bit)

Comment: Apple's macOS licence does not permit this and you are also on the wrong forum.

Answer (score -1):

U can use VMware Fusion on Mac. It's better than virtual box. And also it's stable and easy to use.